# CSS3 transform: rotateY behaves different in Safari and Chrome

Tags: css, css-transforms

I want to use CSS3 tranform on a `<ul>` list with many `<li>` which contains a `<img>` wrapped  with `<a>`.

Please refer to http:// jsfiddle.net/h2T8j/1/

I want to achieve that the `<ul>` is rotatedY by a certain degree and rotateY all the `<li>` by the same degree but in opposite direction to make them look upright along a slanted path.

But the result looks different in Chrome (9.0.1084.30 beta) and Safari (v5.1.5).

I have tried removing the `-webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 0%` from the `<ul>`, but the result will be float out of the `<li>` element. If I am trying to attach a click event to the `<li>` elements, it won't work on Safari.

[see the result in Chrome](http://postimage.org/image/dc6dwjjqv/)

[compared to the result in Safari](http://postimage.org/image/7guts3xyv/)

is there a way to make them work the same way in both browser?

Thank you.

Comment: Yea ... I think you might have found a bug there. `-webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 0%;` on the `ul` appropriately distorts the view for the `li a img` in Chrome, but not in Safari.  If you remove it, it displays correctly in both, but as you say, the browser frames it wrong in Safari and you can't click on the appropriate portions of the `li a img`.

Comment: Perspective is not implemented yet in Chrome. You may call it a bug but its actually not implemented.

Comment: i thought using -webkit-perspective-origin should target both chrome and safari. so there is no way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `<ul>` extremely wide. Actually `10000px`. So if the `<ul>` is only `400px` away from the screen, it won't look good. So i suggest that the `-webkit-perspective` should be enlarged. I've tried changing it to this:

```
ul#looks {
    list-style: none;
    width: 10000px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-perspective: 10000px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thx for you suggestion even though it does not apply in this case. Changing the `-webkit-perspective` on the `<ul>` will affect the distance when you look at the `<li>`. The `<ul>` is 10000px long for it is going to have many `<li>`. I somehow need to use % for the left property. If not, I can do this http://jsfiddle.net/9ymxw/, and  I can get what I want...